# I want to round off 4 columns having decimal values upto 4 decimal places in a csv file

Tags: python, awk, decimal

My input is

```
status,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,extID,medianMeasuredTime,TIMESTAMP,vehicleCount,_id,REPORT_ID,Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
OK,74,50,668,74,1406859600,5,20746220,158324,56.23172069428216,10.104986076057457,56.23172069428216,56.22579478256016,1030,52,71
OK,926,4,981,926,1412098500,0,28060227,210173,56.20913963031665,10.246642527612721,56.20913963031665,56.2026461982616,1106,88,45
```

Expected output:

```
status,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,extID,medianMeasuredTime,TIMESTAMP,vehicleCount,_id,REPORT_ID,Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
OK,74,50,668,74,1406859600,5,20746220,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2317,56.2258,1030,52,71
OK,926,4,981,926,1412098500,0,28060227,210173,56.2091,10.2466,56.2091,56.2026,1106,88,45
```

As you can see i want to round off 10th,11th,12th,13th columns.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{for(i=NF-3;i>NF-7;i--) $i=sprintf("%.4f",$i)}1' file
```

The output:

```
status,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,extID,medianMeasuredTime,TIMESTAMP,vehicleCount,_id,REPORT_ID,Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
OK,74,50,668,74,1406859600,5,20746220,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2317,56.2258,1030,52,71
OK,926,4,981,926,1412098500,0,28060227,210173,56.2091,10.2466,56.2091,56.2026,1106,88,45
```

---

`for(i=NF-3;i>NF-7;i--)` - iterating through 4 fields starting from the 4th field at the end

---

***Note***: if number of columns is always static you can access them directly by their position numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{for(i=10;i<=13;i++) $i=sprintf("%.4f",$i)}1' file
```

---

If you want ***Python*** approach - here we go:

```
with open("yourfile", 'r') as f:
    for k,l in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        if k > 0:
            items = l.split(',')
            items[-4:-8:-1] = ["%.4f" % float(i) for i in items[-4:-8:-1]]
            l = ','.join(items)
        print(l)
```

The output will be the same

Comment: Thankyou sir ! Works perfect ! :)

Comment: @Roshnirajan, I have added Python approach - if you want. It also should work fine

Comment: @EdMorton,  especially for you I've added a note (cause the OP has already made his decision)